# MySQL+Java Transactions

Tags: java, mysql

I'm developing a java application which will run on LAN, i do test today i faced one problem, when insert a new data, other client couldn't see the records even after COMMIT.

I'm using transactions,MySQL INNODB engine, so what i have did is to set the autoCommit Mode to true when ending transactions, then it work.

But why commit didn't revert autoCommit mode to its original state? that strange since tutorial said that when rollback or commit the autoCommitMode will set to true automatically.

any ideas?

Comment: Did the other client refresh their recordset. Remember that a recordset it not tied to the underlying database.

Comment: Yes they refresh the table, but the record not shown, if the other client close the application & reconnect to it then it shown.

Comment: Are you using "connection.commit();" or manualy executing the commit?

Comment: When you refresh the recordset do you close the recordset and rerun the query to reflect the latest data? In other words get a new resultset from the query?

Comment: I have class in my application doing the following: public synchronized boolean endTransaction() {
       try {
        connection.commit();
        System.out.println("Transaction Commited");
       } catch (SQLException sexx) {
           myError(sexx, "22");
           return false;
       } catch (Exception exx) {
           myError(exx, "23");
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once connection is established all autocommit mode changes are ALWAYS made explicitly.
Committing/Rolling back transaction doesn't affect autocommit flag.

If other client sees records after reconnecting it means there is problem at his side.